# Springboot - Can i use Jetty with SL4J

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jetty

I'm working on a SpringBoot - Kotlin - Gradle project and I seem to have run into logger conflicts.  I'm using a library that includes`slf4j` - and thus on startup I'm given the wonderful message of:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/Users/USERNAME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/110cefe2df103412849d72ef7a67e4e91e4266b4/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory

Adding these lines to my `build.gradle` file allows me to run:

```
configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compile.exclude(group: 'ch.qos.logback')
}
```

However my application now starts up with **Tomcat** now instead of **Jetty**.

My dependency block is:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')


    //SpringFox
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-spring-web', version: '2.8.0'

    // SDDF
    compile "org.mitre.sddf:sddf:15.3.2"
}
```

Is there an easy way to resolve this issue and still be able to use **Jetty**?

*Can I put something in my `applicaiton.yml` or `applictaion.properties`?*

Comment: I suggest you do `gradle xxx:dependencies`  where `xxx` is the project path (assuming multi-project build). See [listing dependencies of a build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears that I managed to figure my issue out (by reading the logs a little closer)

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/jstein/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/110cefe2df103412849d72ef7a67e4e91e4266b4/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/jstein/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

I added this to my `build.gradle`

```
configurations.all {
 exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```